# How can I create quantitative stacked bar graphs in Tableau Public?

Tags: r, visualization, ggplot2, tableau-api, stackedbarseries

I have data that looks like this:

```
Subcategory    Title   Value
Sub1           Name1   2
Sub1           Name2   5
Sub2           Name3   4
Sub2           Name4   1
Sub3           Name5   2
Sub3           Name6   7
Sub4           Name1   7
Sub4           Name2   5
Sub5           Name3   4
Sub5           Name4   3
Sub6           Name5   9
Sub6           Name6   1
```

Adding Title to the Row field and Sum(Value) to the Size shelf, I get a horizontal bar chart where the length of the bar is equivalent to the sum of the values for a given title. For example, a bar that is labeled Name1 and is 9 units long, another that is labeled Name2 and is 10 units long, etc. I want to color the bar such that the contribution of a given subcategory to the bar length is painted on the bar. So the Name1 bar would have a blue bar that is 2 units long stacked on a red bar that is 7 units long. The Name 2 bar would have a blue bar 5 units long stacked on an orange bar that is 5 units long.

However, when I add Subcategory to the color shelf, the scale changes so that the length of the bar is now equal to the highest value of the subcategory and the other values are not stacked, but superimposed. Instead of getting a 2 unit blue bar stacked on a 7 unit red bar for a total length of 9, I get a bar of 7 total units with 2 units painted blue.

This changes the interpretation from "What's the category with the highest values (and how do the subcategories contribute to this)?" to "What's the category with the highest subcategory?" because now the Name1 bar is now 7 units whereas the Name2 bar is now only 5 units long and you can't see the other color.

Please let me know if there's a way to do this in Tableau, or if you're a ggplot2 wizard, I'll happily take R code to do the same.

Comment: is "size shelf" and "color shelf" tableau terminology?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578961/how-to-better-create-stacked-bar-graphs-with-multiple-variables-from-ggplot2/3784878#3784878 OP outlined how to create a 100% stacked bar

Comment: Yes, those are Tableau-specific terms. I don't particularly like the Tableau interface, but does make some damn pretty graphs if your data fits their model.

Comment: got it - It took me a minute to figure out what you needed, but I got it figured out, as did rcs as we gave you two nearly identical answers. `position = stack` is the default for `geom_bar` I believe. As for the long titles, you could manually insert some `\n` to force them to wrap at a given width and/or look into adjusting the angle of the axis to suit your purposes. That may work better if you reorient the bars to vertical though. Anyhow - the code to edit such things is: `opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle = 90)`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this, but I am not sure if the coloring is right:

```
library("ggplot2")
p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=Title, y=Value, fill=Subcategory)) +
       geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
       coord_flip()
print(p)
```

[image: ggplot example]

Comment: Checked this and it does work. It's acting a little screwy when I use it on the whole dataset because some of my titles are really long, but it does work using a fixed-size hash of the titles.

Comment: I subsetted my dataset to include only the 44 rows that I want of the hundreds, yet it was still plotting hundreds of titles on the axis. I needed `p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=factor(Title), y=Value, fill=Subcategory)) + geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + coord_flip()` Now I just need to figure out why ggplot has flipped my graph so the bars extend right-to-left instead of the normal left-to-right and how to limit the title to a fixed number of characters. I'm going to check into `opts(axis.text.x)` to see if there's a way to do this second and maybe the flipping will fix itself.

Comment: How would you edit the above such that the Titles were plotted in order of total value? In the example above, the order would be Name5, Name2, Name1, Name3, Name6, Name4.

Comment: Change the order of the factor levels: `dat <- transform(dat, Title=reorder(Title, Value, sum))`

Comment: Thanks so much. This works. I was looking for a way to add a `reorder` statement to my `ggplot` call, but I like this better. Out of curiosity, is it possible to add a `reorder` statement to the `ggplot` call to do this, or is the separate `transform` required? Also, is there somewhere I can find a list of all the arguments I can pass to `reorder`? I know of sum, mean, and median.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want in ggplot:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Title,y = Value, fill = Subcategory)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Tableau, put Title on Rows, Value on Columns and Subcategory on Color.

I put an example up on Tableau Public -- http://public.tableausoftware.com/views/QuantitativeStackedBars/Sheet1?:embed=y

[image: Here's what it looks like.]