# How to plot a stacked barplot in ggplot2, with different shades of the given color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set Region as below.

```
Region   Color    0-25    25-50     50-75   75-100

AF       Green      51%     14%     24%     11%

AP       Red        5%      12%     9%      74%

EU       Yellow     18%     3%      36%     43%

Global   Green      34%     11%     19%     36%

LA       Green      44%     23%     22%     11%

NA       Green      100%    0%      0%      0%
```

I would like to plot a stacked bar graph using ggplot for the above data set.
I am looking for:, say when Global data is plotted, I Would like the color to be Green for range between `0-25` , dark green for `25-50`, light Grey color for `50-75` and dark Grey between `75-100`.
Simmilary for the others, red, dark red, Light grey and dark grey for AP region.

Something on the similar lines:[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578961/how-to-better-create-stacked-bar-graphs-with-multiple-variables-from-ggplot2?rq=1)

Any tips on this would be of a much help. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach, using green.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Region = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, NA), .Label = c("AF", 
"AP", "EU", "Global", "LA", "Region"), class = "factor"), Color = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Color", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"
), class = "factor"), `0-25` = c(51, 5, 18, 34, 44, 100), `26-50` = c(14, 
12, 3, 11, 23, 0), `51-75` = c(24, 9, 36, 19, 22, 0), `76-100` = c(11, 
74, 43, 36, 11, 0)), .Names = c("Region", "Color", "0-25", "26-50", 
"51-75", "76-100"), row.names = 2:7, class = "data.frame")
```

Then, `melt` served as `tidyr` and `cut` created the factor for colors.

```
df.m <- melt(df, id.vars = "Region", measure.vars = 3:6)
df.m$color.bin <- cut(x = df.m$value, breaks = c(0, 26, 51, 76, 100))
df.m$color.bin <- as.factor(df.m$color.bin)
```

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS**

I then added a factor variable for ggplot to use.

```
df.m$shade <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "p","p","p","p","p","p","p","p")
```

The final step was a first run with ggplot and stacking and to set the colors for fill manually.  Although there are six regions, I matched your color scheme for the first four only.  You can complete the rest.  I added the `color` argument to show divisions between the stacked segments.  I added the `guides` call to eliminate the long legend of letters and colors:

```
ggplot(df.m, aes(x = Region, y = value, fill = shade)) +  
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", color = "black") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("forestgreen", "lightcoral", "lemonchiffon", "blue", "grey30", "grey30",
                               "lightgreen", "lightcoral", "lemonchiffon", "lightblue", "grey30", "grey30",
                               "lightgreen","lightcoral", "yellow", "lightblue", "grey30", "grey30", 
                               "lightgreen", "grey70","yellow", "blue", "grey30", "grey30")) +
  guides(fill = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: @ LawyeR, Thanks for the suggestion. But what I am looking at his, for the region AP, the color is Red , so it should be light Red from 0-25, then darker red from 25-50 and 50-75 grey and 75-100 dark Grey.

I would want the same colors to be as in the data frame . Is that possible

Comment: But AP has only two color bins: 0-25 and 51-76.  So only two colors.  Substitute this line for the final line of code and see light red (pink) and red.  scale_fill_manual(values = c("pink", "red", "grey30", "grey70"))

Comment: @ LawyeR, Thanks for the reply and support again. Yes I need to color the two pins for AP with pink and red. And I also need the region between 51-76 to be light and dark grey. 

for EU its yellow. should I use the scale_fill_manual(values = c("pale yellow", "yellow", "grey30", "grey70")) for every single bar graph.

Comment: No, the scale_fill will color each segment of the stacked bars, all of them, by the chosen colors.  You do not need to handle each bar separately.  Choose any four colors you want; you must have the same number as you have cuts of the data, however.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: thanks for the support again. what I want is to have each bar colored with different shades based on the column color in the data set. for AP its red, EU its yellow. Is it possible to add different colors to each geom_bar that we want.